# How do I specify an autoIncrement column in SORM?

Tags: sorm

I'd like to add the autoIncrement property for a numeric column in SORM. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to configure this in SORM and there's a reason: in practice auto-increment property is only needed for id-columns, and [SORM manages ids for you](http://sorm-framework.org/Documentation.html#persisted_trait_and_ids).

If you're, however, absolutely sure that you need this, you can always let SORM generate the schema and then alter such details according to your needs with db-administration tool. But again, I'm sure that you're approaching the problem incorrectly. What do you need that for?

Comment: I took another look at my data models and realized I don't autoIncrement for a non-id field. Thanks.